# How to Change this mssql code to MySql

Tags: mysql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

This code returns the results that i want but i need it in MySQL

Thanks in Advance

```
SET @searchstring = 'hot spicy'

set @SQLStatement = 'Select * FROM dbo._TEST_'
IF LEN(@searchstring)>0
    SET @SQLStatement=@SQLStatement+ ' WHERE tast LIKE '+CHAR(39)+'%'
SET @searchstring=Replace (@searchstring,' ', '%'+CHAR(39)+' AND tast LIKE '+CHAR(39)+'%')
IF LEN(@searchstring)>0
    SET @SQLStatement=@SQLStatement+ @searchstring +'%'+ CHAR(39)
IF LEN(@searchstring)>0
    EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQLStatement
```

GO>

Comment: $where = '';
$string = "thi sdas asd";
$search = explode(" ",$string);
if(sizeof($search)>1)
{
$where = "1=1";
    foreach($search=>$key as $val){
        $where .= "or items like %".$val."%"; 
    }
}
else
{

$where = "items like %".$search[0]."%"
}

$query = mysql_query("SELECT  * FROM menu WHERE ".$where)

Comment: Read the MySQL documentation on [prepared statements](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html)